# Can't run bitcoind on OS X

Tags: mac, openssl

I get the following error:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bitcoind
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Recompiling fails too with similar "abort trap" messages.

I am 99% sure I have messed up my openssl stuff in some way, though am unsure how to rectify that.

Comment: Did you compile yourself?

Comment: yes. though `make` fails now in a similar way.

Comment: `brew reinstall openssl`?

Comment: make still fails with: 5 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [bench/bench_bitcoin-data.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1